# Can Windows Media Center 7 be made to play from ISO files?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, windows-media-center, iso-image

Is there a way to make Windows Media Center 7 to play iso images?  I have many DVDs ripped to iso.  Right now I just play them by navigating to them in Windows Explorer, right-clicking an selecting open with VLC.  It be nice to have access to these from the nice Media Center GUI.

Anyone have a way for MediaCenter to recognize and play these like VLC or any other nice user interface way of navigating and playing my iso dvd rips?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need [**Daemon Tools Lite**](http://www.daemon-tools.cc/kor/downloads/daemon) and [**mceDTools**](http://www.codeplex.com/mceDTools) to allow integration into Windows Media Center 7. Check out the complete guide [**here**](http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/08/04/how-to-play-your-dvds-in-windows-media-center-without-leaving-the-couch/).

Comment: did you EVER get mceDTOOLS to work properly? i gave up on it, it's a royal PITA :) ... IF you're a fan of Daemon Tools, try myLoader.

Comment: Yea I can not seem to get mceDTOOLS working either

Comment: Didn't Daemon Tools start bundling spyware with their distribution? I vote for MagicDisc from MagicISO.

Comment: Bundle? Yes. Require? No.

Answer (score 3):

I use Shark007s codec pack, which lets me play ISO files from inside media center. I use media Browser usually to view them with, so I don't know if it works from the standard videos section

Comment: +1 for the media browser reference -- that looks like a great add-in.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using MagicISO - not necessarily for video specifically, but it does quite nicely for me.  http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-magicdisc-overview.htm

Answer (score 1):

I have returned to share my success in looking for the same thing;

[My Movies](http://www.mymovies.dk/) is THE solution, the sites clear enough to explain but basically aslong as you install the slysoft 'virtual clonedrive' (freeware) your sorted, and it organises and presents the films beautifully in WMC.

Just to confirm, it can show you all of your iso's with artwork, info, special features AND play them - All Inside WMC. 
Also stumbled across media center studio which i'm happily using to customise the start menu.

Hope this helps someone
[*1st time post only allows 1 hyperlink]

slysoft.com/da/download.html/

adventmediacenter.com/

Answer (score -1):

mount the image with **[WinCDEmu](http://wincdemu.sysprogs.org/)**.

Comment: Will this solution require me to mount each iso before playing it?  If I have to use Windows Explorer to locate each iso and mount it before playing it in Media Center I might as well just right click the file and have it play in vlc.  I am mainly looking for a good user interface solution to browse through my ripped dvds

Comment: i'm afraid this is not possible. Windows Media Center does not support ISO files and i don't know of any plugins that work the way you want it without the inconvenience of mounting the ISO first.

Comment: Just because you don't know of anything doesn't mean it's not possible.

Comment: -1 WinCDEmu is unstable and crashes

Answer (score -1):

Use XBMC MediaCenter that plays ISO files out of the box.